# linux socket: lifetime of ancillary data for sendmsg

Tags: linux, sockets

I use cmsg to activate timestamping on linux socket tx.

```
ssize_t sendWithOptions
(int sd, std::vector<uint8_t> &payload, uint32_t destIP, int flags)
{
    msghdr msg { };
    .... // filling standard
    std::array<uint8_t, CMSG_LEN(sizeof(__u32))> buf;
    msg.msg_control = buf.data();
    msg.msg_controlen = buf.size();

    auto cmsg { CMSG_FIRSTHDR ( &msg ) };
    cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = SO_TIMESTAMPING;
    cmsg->cmsg_len = buf.size();

    *(reinterpret_cast<__u32>(CMSG_DATA (cmsg)) = static_cast<__u32>(flags);
    return sendmsg ( sd, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT );
}
```

Leaving the function, "buf" is automatically destroyed, but does sendmsg need this buffer to live longer?
Do I have a guarantee that the function does not need this buffer once it has returned the number of bytes sent.

Answer (score 2):

Except for specific interfaces, it is generally the case that operating system calls do not rely on user-space to maintain data structures affecting their operation after they are finished. The exceptions will be spelled out in the manual pages.

With `sendmsg`, in particular, you can rely on the call to complete immediately - whether successful or not. It's fine therefore to use a dynamically allocated buffer as you're doing, and destroy it immediately after the call.

As an example of one exception, `aio_write(2)` is specifically intended to allow user-space to queue a write operation that will be completed asynchronously. For this call, the data is not consumed until it can be successfully written. Hence, you must not modify the data structures provided in the call until you have confirmed it is complete. That caveat is called out in the `NOTES` section of the manual page:

> ... The control block must not be changed while the write operation  is  in  progress.  The buffer area being written out must not be accessed during the operation or undefined results may occur.  The memory areas involved must remain valid.

In summary: check the manual page for the system call. But most of the time, you don't need to worry about it.